# Xamarin Forms Update value in App.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I want to set and get a variable in my App.xaml.cs, so I use this code:

```
static User user { get; set; }

public static User User
{
    get
    {
        if(user == null)
        {
            user = new User();
        }
        return user;
    }
    set
    {
        User = value;
    }
}
```

And inside a page I call this line:

```
App.User = response.user;
```

But after that line is fired, the app doesn't hit the next line and after a few seconds the app crashes. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this causes an infinite loop

```
set
{
    User = value;
}
```

you should be doing

```
set
{
    user = value;
}
```